# res.cookie works on Localhost and Postman but doesn't work on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies

res.cookie set browser cookie on localhost but doesn't set browser cookie after production and still I can find set-cookie in response header.
I don't see any cors problem. I use Digitalocean App to deploy my node server.

Here is my code -

```
res.cookie('ckstate', 'logged', {
                httpOnly: false, 
                sameSite: router.get("env") === "development" ? true : "none", 
                secure: router.get("env") === "development" ? false : true
            })
            .status(200)
            .json(others)
```

Here is the POST request from my React client -

```
await axios.post(API_URL, user, { withCredentials: true })
        .then(res => {
            Auth.refreshAuth();
            history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            setMessage('Wrong Credentials. Try again.');
        })
```

[Here is the Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpb2e.png)

Comment: Is your production server running on https ?

Comment: Yes, production server is running on https